# How to use Sharding in arangodb?

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I am new to sharding feature of arangodb, I have learned various documents related to this, but still can't find the way to configure it. Anybody please provide the **step-by-step procedure to setup sharding** or **any refrence** which is useful for me. I am using arangodb with node.js and angularJS on linux mint.
I often visit https://docs.arangodb.com and these are little useful 
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/cluster/ and [How to set clusters and sharding in ArangoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022729/how-to-set-clusters-and-sharding-in-arangodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharding is only available in ArangoDB if it is clustered.
Other than hat, you configure the number of shards a collection is distributed into when you create the collection. The sharding is completely transparent to your AQL queries - the ArangoDB Coordinator instances do all the heavy lifting for you. This is probably why sharding doesn't appear in a more detailed way in the docs.

The easiest way to set up an ArangoDB Cluster is to use the cloud service, [ArangoGraph Insights Platform](https://cloud.arangodb.com/). You can also run a local cluster, for example, using the [ArangoDB Starter](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/cluster/deployment/using-the-arangodb-starter/).

Comment: I had read the manual (https://docs.arangodb.com/2.5/Installing/Cluster.html)  and configured accordingly. what next? I want to partition my database into shardes, but I dont know what to do next

Comment: With ArangoDB 3.0 [the cluster setup procedure changes](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Deployment/Mesos.html).Once you've set up a cluster, [you create a collection and specify the number of shards](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Sharding/index.html). The shard key controls the distribution of the documents over the shards. You should choose a number of shards bigger than your currently available cluster nodes, so if you increase the number of nodes, shards can be moved to these new nodes. You then can use regular AQL to query your data.

Comment: got it. I have done what you have suggested but How do I come to know if actually shards are created or not? and how does it stores our data?

Comment: If you open the webinterface in your cluster, the collection properties will give you the number of shards.

Comment: no..it shows as usual..I'm using arango 2.8, should I upgrade it?

Comment: Yes, you have to upgrade to 3.0 if you want to use the new cluster features (as well as the new web interface and many other features). Have a look at the recent [blog posts](https://www.arangodb.com/blog/) and see [Upgrading to 3.0](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Upgrading/Upgrading30.html) in the documentation.